# Is there a usable Queuable interface anywhere in the .NET BCL?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The `Queue<T>` type in .NET has a method

```cs
void Enqueue(T item);
```

But there is no interface that wraps this method. Is there a (preferably single method) interface with the same type signature elsewhere in the BCL? I'd like to be able to develop two packages, one which defines data structures that implement the abstraction and one which uses the abstraction and avoid creating an abstractions package required by both.

Comment: I'm entirely sure what you are asking for.  Can you elaborate?  As far as something with the same signature as `Queue.Enqueue`, does `Action<T>` work?

Comment: Let me see if I got this correct, you are developing an abstract data structure library and a concrete implementation of that library. You want your abstract library to extend `IQueue` while the concrete library extends `IQueue` through it? And you are looking for an `IQueue` but it doesn't exist?

Comment: It's unclear why there would be a single-method interface for this - just `Enqueue`. Your own class/interface might have a reason for a method that enqueues something without a method for dequeueing it, but then the commonality between your class and `Queue<T>` would be coincidental.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, `Action<T>` does match, but is inconvenient since it's not very IoC-container friendly (hence looking for an interface).

@AvinKavish so we're basically talking one library that implements the interface, one that uses the interface. And I don't need every method of `Queue`, just `Enqueue`.

@ScottHannen If you think about it, there's already a single-purpose interface for consuming values: it's `IEnumerable<T>`/`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. What I'm looking for is an interface for producing/pushing values. I don't need it to be type-compatible with `Queue<T>`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only interface that really matches this is `IObserver<T>`, which is a little more complex (it supports error notification and termination).

The Channels API supports ChannelWriter but that's an abstract class. As observed above, Action also works if you don't need to be able to configure easily via IoC.